# Add width of a div element from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

In the aspx page I have div with `id="progressBar"` and `runat="server"`.I need to add width of the div from code behind in C#.

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set it's [`Style` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.style.aspx), like this:

```
progressBar.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width] = "200px";
//or just use a string:
progressBar.Style["width"] = "200px";
```

---

Alternatively, you can give it a CSS class, define this in your CSS:

```
.progress { width: 200px; }
```

And assign that class in your markup like this:

```
<div id="progressBar" runat="server" class="progress">
```

Or in your code-behind:

```
progressBar.Attributes["class"] = "progress";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in this way also :-

**progressBar.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "200px");**

Answer (score 0):

progressBar.Style.Add("width", "300px");